# Ran npm run start in Mac terminal to update and start Protractor webdriver server got an ERR message

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, protractor, automated-tests

Hope someone can help with this.  I was trying to update and start protractor from my terminal for the 1st time and I got this error message.

The command I used was

```
npm run start
```

I had a look at my  package.json script and that seems fine.  Did I miss something?

**npm.json file**

```
{
  "name": "LocatorTraining",

  "dependencies": {

  "protractor":  "^5.4.1"

  },


  "scripts": {
    "webdriver-update": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-start": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "protractor": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor configurations.js",
    "start": "npm run webdriver-manager update &&npm run webdriver-manager start"
  }

}
```

**Message from terminal**

```
JohnSmith-MacBook-Air:~ JohnSmith$ npm run start
    npm ERR! Darwin 17.7.0
    npm ERR! argv "/Users/JohnSmith/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/npm" "run" "start"
    npm ERR! node v7.2.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
    npm ERR! path /Users/JohnSmith/package.json
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -2
    npm ERR! syscall open

    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/JohnSmith/package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/JohnSmith/package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
    npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent 

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /Users/JohnSmith/npm-debug.log
```

So following a comment from below I tried to run npm run start at project level.

I got the following response.

```
Ran the npm run start from project level> LocatorTraining@ start /Users/JohnSmith/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining
> npm run webdriver-manager update &&npm run webdriver-manager start

npm ERR! Darwin 17.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/JohnSmith/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/npm" "run" "webdriver-manager" "update"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9

npm ERR! missing script: webdriver-manager
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/JohnSmith/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Darwin 17.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/JohnSmith/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/npm" "run" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! LocatorTraining@ start: `npm run webdriver-manager update &&npm run webdriver-manager start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the LocatorTraining@ start script 'npm run webdriver-manager update &&npm run webdriver-manager start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the LocatorTraining package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run webdriver-manager update &&npm run webdriver-manager start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs LocatorTraining
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls LocatorTraining
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/JohnSmith/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/npm-debug.log
```

I then tried to access npm debug log at project level

```
/Users/JohnSmith/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/npm-debug.log: Permission denied
```

Comment: Run your test from the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

(This is better served as a comment, but alas I am unable to still)

What directory did you run `npm run start` in? It seems like you ran the correct command but in the wrong location. You want to make sure you run the commands from the project directory.

That is, if your `package.json` file is at `/Users/xx/protractorProj/package.json` you need to run the `npm run start` command from `/Users/xx/protractorProj`.

Comment: OK, modified the code show clearly see where I ran this from.

Comment: It seems like you are now running it in the correct location, but `npm run start` calls a couple other npm scripts. The trouble is, you don't have those scripts. They appear to closely resemble the ones you _do_ have, though. Should `npm run start` be calling `npm run webdriver-update` and `npm run webdriver-start` instead? I'm coming at this from `npm` not `protractor`, btw, I don't know `protractor`.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look in your scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "webdriver-update": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-start": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "protractor": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor configurations.js",
    "start": "npm run webdriver-manager update &&npm run webdriver-manager start"
  }
```

Also, in the error traceback, you find:

```
npm ERR! missing script: webdriver-manager
```

There is a mismatch between the available run scripts and the ones used in start.
The start run script should be:

```
"start": "npm run webdriver-update && npm run webdriver-start"
```